# How can I access parent class variable?

Tags: php

I would like to access parent class variable. How can I access parent class variable?
here is example:

```
class myclass {
    var $parentvar;
    function __construct() {
        $this->parentvar = 'Some text or array';
    }
}

class anotherClass extends myclass {
    function __construct(argument)
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function print_var() {
        echo $parent->parentvar;
    }
}
```

Please suggest me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `$this->parentvar`

When you extend a class, all of the public and protected properties and methods become available to the instance scope of your child class.

Comment: It should be added that when you don't specify `protected`, `public` or `private` it defaults the variable/function to `public`. [*Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). OP, you do not have to use `parent::__construct` unless you're using the `$argument` for something.

Comment: As soon as you define a constructor in the child class the parent one will not be called automatically, so if this is a complete class then then the child constructor could just be deleted. I presume that it is an incomplete example though.

Comment: I'm assuming it's incomplete as well, seeing as `$argument` is only specified in the child class (albeit, he'd be able to get the variable with `func_get_args` even if it wasn't specified in the function, although that's a horrible solution).